# problem with installing Pygame on Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame, anaconda

I want to install pygame on python. I have ubuntu 20.04 (which has python3.8 already installed) and Anaconda.
pip is connected to Anaconda: `which pip` shows it's at `/home/mohammad/anaconda3/bin/pip`.

I use **pip** to install **pygame** on **Anaconda**. But `pip install pygame` shows error. How can I install pygame on Anaconda?

I can simply install pygame by deactivating Anaconda Enviroment and using pip which installs it on system python (It shouldn't have any problem). But I want to have pygame on Anaconda.

I don't really know where the problem is.

```
$ pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/mohammad/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z7x7jtmx/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z7x7jtmx/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ctnap_n6
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-z7x7jtmx/pygame/
    Complete output (25 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...
    
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'freetype2' found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'freetype2' found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'freetype2' found
    
    Hunting dependencies...
    WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
    WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
    Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python3 -m pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

Please try running the above mentioned code on your platform.

There isn't a build of 2.0.0.dev3 for Python 3.8. Python 3.8 wasn't out when dev3 was released. You want the latest, so change your command to that .

However , if that also doesn't help you as well , try `sudo apt install python3-pygame`

Comment: Thanks. It helped. pip was trying to install python 1.9.6. But I also use `apt install python3-pygame` and it installed pygame 1.9.6 on my system successfuly! How did it worked?